# java program to download artifacts and compare

Tags: java, artifactory

I want to download the builds artifacts from Jfrogartifactory and compare the two builds artifacts. looking for any API or java program to download artifacts and compare, Anyone please share any resource to refer.

Comment: What would you like to find out in the comparison?

Comment: the build will have the jar files and war files i want to get the difference in contents of those files and get the output in a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no 'easy' way to download the build dependencies using Java.
However with [JFrog CLI](https://jfrog.com/getcli) you can download the build dependencies easily:

```
jfrog rt dl '*' --build=BUILD_NAME/BUILD_NUMBER
```

If you still want to download build dependencies you can use the [Build Info Extractor](https://bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-jars/build-info). Use [ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/clientConfiguration/client/ArtifactoryBuildInfoClient.java) to download build info and [ArtifactoryDependenciesClient](https://github.com/jfrog/build-info/blob/master/build-info-extractor/src/main/java/org/jfrog/build/extractor/clientConfiguration/client/ArtifactoryDependenciesClient.java) to download the build artifacts.